# Precompiling multiple programs

Tags: webgl2

So far i have had good succes in rendering to an output texture with the use of input data (texture)

In the interest of speed, i want a set of precompiled webgl programs ready for "use" depending on what i want to do

is it possible to (pseudocode)

```
 createProgram #1
 createProgram #2
 createProgram #3
 createProgram #4

1: useProgram #1
2: attach selected frame buffers/uniforms
3: setViewPort (depended on output framebuffer attached texture)
3: drawArrays
4: readPixels
```

At this point i want to use another program (#2 for example) 
what happens to the attached uniforms and buffers to program #1
do i need to clear them? can i leav them in place and re-use them later?

If i issue "useProgram #1" are all the active uniforms and framebuffers i selected for program #1 still intact??

Comment: The answer is here, https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html
I didnt delete the question, because I think its still usefull for others

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple programs setup at init time. That's the normal thing to do.

notes:

#### Uniform locations are unique to each program

For example let's make 2 shader programs with exactly the same content and try to use the uniform location from one program with the other program.

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

const vs = `
void main() {
  // draw a 10 pixel "POINT" in the center of the canvas
  gl_PointSize = 10.0;
  gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = color;
}
`;

// make 2 identical programs
// compile shaders, link programs
const p1 = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
const p2 = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);

// look up color location from first program
const colorLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(p1, 'color');

// try to use colorLoc with second program
gl.useProgram(p2);  // make p2 the current program
gl.uniform4fv(colorLoc, [1, 0, 0, 1]);

console.log('error:', glEnumToString(gl, gl.getError()));

function glEnumToString(gl, v) {
  return Object.keys(WebGLRenderingContext.prototype)
      .filter(k => gl[k] === v)
      .join(' | ');
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

It fails with `INVALID_OPERATION`. You need to look up locations separate for each program

#### uniform state is per program

so for example let's make the same programs, we'll set the uniforms on them before rendering with them to show that the uniform settings are "per program"

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
void main() {
  // draw a 10 pixel "POINT" in the center of the canvas
  gl_PointSize = 10.0;
  gl_Position = position;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = color;
}
`;

// make 3 identical programs
// compile shaders, link programs, force position to location 0 by calling 
// bindAttribLocation
const p1 = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs], ['position']);
const p2 = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs], ['position']);
const p3 = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs], ['position']);

// look up color location for each program
const colorLocP1 = gl.getUniformLocation(p1, 'color');
const colorLocP2 = gl.getUniformLocation(p2, 'color');
const colorLocP3 = gl.getUniformLocation(p3, 'color');

// set the color uniform on each program
gl.useProgram(p1);
gl.uniform4fv(colorLocP1, [1, 0, 0, 1]);
gl.useProgram(p2);
gl.uniform4fv(colorLocP2, [0, 1, 0, 1]);
gl.useProgram(p3);
gl.uniform4fv(colorLocP3, [0, 0, 1, 1]);

// draw with each program
const positionIndex = 0; 
gl.vertexAttrib2f(positionIndex, -0.5, 0);
gl.useProgram(p1);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);  // draw 1 point

gl.vertexAttrib2f(positionIndex, 0.0, 0);
gl.useProgram(p2);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);  // draw 1 point

gl.vertexAttrib2f(positionIndex, 0.5, 0);
gl.useProgram(p3);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);  // draw 1 point
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

#### attributes are part of vertex array state

Each enabled attribute has a buffer attached when you call `vertexAttribPointer`

#### texture units are global state.

Which texture unit a particular program's uniform sampler uses is program state (it's a uniform so it's program state). But what textures are on each texture unit is global state.  In other words if you have a shader program with

```
uniform sampler2D foo;
```

Then you tell that shader program which texture unit to use with

```
gl.uniform1i(fooLocation, indexOfTextureUnit);
```

But but state if each texture unit itself is global state. For example if it was implemented in JavaScript

```
gl = {
  activeTexture: 0,
  textureUnits: [
    { TEXTURE_2D: null, TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP: null, ... },
    { TEXTURE_2D: null, TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP: null, ... },
    { TEXTURE_2D: null, TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP: null, ... },
    { TEXTURE_2D: null, TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP: null, ... },
    { TEXTURE_2D: null, TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP: null, ... },
    { TEXTURE_2D: null, TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP: null, ... },
    ... MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_UNITS ...
  ],
};
```

and the functions that manipulate textures work on those units like this

```
gl = {
  activeTexture(unitEnum) {
    this.activeTexture = unitEnum - gl.TEXTURE0;
  }
  bindTexture(target, texture) {
    const textureUnit = this.textureUnits[this.activeTexture];
    textureUnit[target] = texture;
  }
  texImage2D(target, ...args) {
    const textureUnit = this.textureUnits[this.activeTexture];
    updateDataToTexture(textureUnit[target], ...args);
  }
}
```

#### Current framebuffer bindings are global state.